# How to use DefaultEditorKit in an AbstractAction

Tags: java, action

My notepad program that I'm writing uses AbstractActions for each item in the JMenuBar, and I want to keep it consistent that way throughout my code. And now I'm implementing Cut, Copy, Paste into the program but I'm unsure of how to do that with Action.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit;

public class Home {
    static Action Cut = new AbstractAction("Cut-Action") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Where I want to use cut
            new DefaultEditorKit.CutAction();
        }
    };

    static public JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Edit");

        menu.add(Cut); // Adds the cut action

        // adds the non-action method
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CutAction());
        item.setText("Cut-NonAction");
        menu.add(item);

        menuBar.add(menu);
        return menuBar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Home");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JMenuBar menuBar = createMenuBar();
        frame.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JTextPane txt = new JTextPane();
        JScrollPane s = new JScrollPane(txt);

        frame.add(s, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

How would I be able to use the cut action in my abstract action??

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: my variable names don't start with an upper care letter??

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with a little bit of trial and error.

I changed this code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    new DefaultEditorKit().CutAction();
}
```

to:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Action cut = new DefaultEditorKit.CutAction();
    cut.actionPerformed(e);
}
```

Comment: Don't do this it is not the proper way to use the default Actions. Also, there is no need to continually create new instances of the same Action.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I be able to use the cut action in my abstract action??

Why are you trying to do this? The is not the way to use the Actions from the editor kit.

This is the proper way to use the actions:

```
JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CutAction());
```

Or if you happen to need the CutAction on a menu and on a toolbar you would use code like:

```
Action cut = new DefaultEditorKit.CutAction();
cut.putValue(Action.NAME, "Cut");

JMenuItem cutMenuItem = new JMenuItem( cut );
JButton cutButton = new JButton( cut );
```

Now the same Action is shared which means you can enable/disable the Action and both components will be affected. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to avoid initializing each JMenuItem but I came to end up doing that to display the keyboard shortcuts on my program. And the solution I came up with works :), but I'm going to be changing my whole code. I'm new to java and still learning about actions, etc.